# Can this simple form of double extension set theory escape inconsistency?

Tags: first-order-logic, alternative-set-theories

The following theory is another way of dealing with naive comprehension. It uses the double extension principle, broadly speaking similar to what's used in [Double Extension Set Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-alternative/#DoubExteSetTheoCuri) of Andrzej Kisielewicz (1998), but *possibly* simpler?

Language: first order logic

Primitives: Equality =, and Two set membership relations $\in_1; \in_2$

**Extensionality:** for i=1,2:
$\forall x,y [\forall z (z \in_i x \leftrightarrow z \in_i y ) \to x=y]$

Define: $\text {uniform}(x) \iff \forall y (y \in_1 x \leftrightarrow y \in_2 x)$

**Comprehension:** If $\phi^1$ is a formula not using predicate $\in_2$, in which $x$ doen'st occur free, then all closures of:$$  \exists x \forall y (y \in_2 x \leftrightarrow \phi^1)$$; are axioms.

Define: $x=\{y|\phi^1\}^2 \iff \forall y (y \in_2 x \leftrightarrow \phi^1)$

**Uniformity:** If $\phi^1$ is a formula not using predicate $\in_2$, whose free variables are among $y,x_1,..,x_n$, and $\phi^1(x|y)$ is the formula obtained by merely replacing all occurrences of the symbol $``y"$ in $\phi^1$ by the symbol $``x"$, then all closures of:
$$x_1,..,x_n \text { are uniform } \to \\\forall x [x=\{y|\phi^1\}^2 \land \neg \phi^1(x|y) \to \text {uniform}(x)]$$; are axioms.

**Induction:** over naturals for any formula $\phi$.

> Questions:
>
> 1. Is there a clear inconsistency with this theory?
> 2. Assuming consistency, what's the strength of this theory?
> 3. If we upgrade Induction to Transfinite Induction, would that render the theory inconsistent?

Comment: If I get this right, $x,y$ are not free in $\phi^1$, hence the only things Comprehension can give us is an empty$^2$ and a universal$^2$ set?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, yes that was a typo, I've added $y$. Thanks